# How to set path for specific Android API in Visual Studio 2015 for using usb debugging

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, usb-debugging

I am working with Xamarin and getting the following error while using usb debugging,
Although the specifed API exists on my PC but still it is giving me the following error.
How can I change the folder's path shown in error log to the actual path that exists on my PC.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
> Error     Could not find android.jar for API Level 23. This means the
> Android SDK platform for API Level 23 is not installed. Either install
> it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...),
> or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that
> is installed.
>
> (D:\Android SDK\platforms\android-23\android.jar
> missing.) MyApp.Droid         Build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right Click `Solution` in the solution explorer
2. Expand `Common Properties`>`Debug Source Files`
3. Delete all the paths listed in the box on the right side
4. click `Apply`> `OK`

[image]

Comment: Care to elaborate on what this does? It didn't work for me.